# Use of "saber" in this context

Tags: selección-de-palabras, uso-de-palabras

This is usually figured out  by reading, but I don't really much in Spanish.

`Saber` means to know a fact:

> sé las noticias de mis abuelos.

`Conocer` mainly means to be familiar with.

Here is an example that is kinda ambiguous:

> David conoce a muchos músicos.

I would usually put **sabe** based on this one:

> David sabe del béisbol.

Comment: Please edit your question to clearly state what you're confused about.

Comment: Why is it David conoce a muchos múscos, not sabe?

Comment: You should edit your question, not add a comment. Right now, you are asking nothing. Please remember that questions in Stack Exchange should also be useful for future visitors.

Comment: ¿qué quieres saber?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you posted in your question, we use `saber` when we want to convey knowledge or mastery of skills and `conocer` to imply something more like *"be familiar with"*, **whether is knowledge or people**. Thus, we use `conocer`, when you know people, but also when you have a decent understanding about something, which is a very similar meaning to `saber`.

To clarify on your example about "David conoce a muchos músicos." `Conoce` is OK, since you are conveying that he knows a lot of people (musicians). You could have used `saber` if you were saying something like

> David **sabe** (mucho) de música  <sub>David **knows** (a lot) about music</sub>

So, use `conocer` when you want to say "knows somebody".

In "David is familiar with many (types of) musics" you should go with `conocer`, implying "his lore about music includes these many different types of musics".

> David **conoce** muchos tipos de música. Conoce músicas étnicas de muchas culturas, música clásica y música moderna.

In "David knows (how to play ) many musics/songs" you need to go with `saber` (Davis has the knowledge to play these many different instruments or these many different rhythms or musics)

> David **sabe** tocar todos estos instrumentos.

Knowing how to play an instrument is "saber tocar un instrumento" in Spanish. Knowing about the existence of types of music and its intricacies is "conocer esos tipos de música".

To explore more the differences between `saber` and `conocer`, you could see [this related question (with its answers)](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/10546/5481) or [this other](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/12095/5481).

Comment: Wait so my example is like david is familiar with many musics. But when I use saber in david sabe a muchos musicas, it means david knows (how to play ) many musics/songs right?

Comment: I'll edit the answer and address that. You already had a Spanish translation for the sentence, you the question didn't fully convey that.

Comment: @Doeser *saber a* means *to taste like*. So *sabe a muchos músicos* means that he tastes like/of many musicians.

Comment: Omg, I forgot that apply.

Comment: Wait but saber a usually apply to food. Not person

Comment: @Doeser, ["saber"](http://buscon.rae.es/drae/srv/search?id=BKBAlquJMDXX2SGhCSwU) has two meanings: To **know** something and to **taste** like something. With the "a" preposition, since like in "saber **a**" the meaning is "to taste like". "Saber a músico" doesn't make sense (unless you have licked one of the musicians an can describe what they taste like...)

Answer (score 4):

You must use **conocer** when the meaning of "knowing" is closer to the notion of *being familiar or acquainted with something or someone*.

And use **saber** when the meaning of "knowing" is closer to the notion of *being able or have skills with something*.

In using both words are sometimes confused for non-native speakers, but are quite different: **conocer** relates with *recognition* and **saber** relates to the *wisdom*.

Therefore, you can't "saber a una persona". You only can "saber" knowledges as data, languages, techniques, science or similar matters.

Comment: Here is another ambiguous case: mis amigos quieren saber/ conocer mi paiz.

Comment: It sounds more like my friends want to know what my country is. Instead of just the country

Comment: They want to know a _data_: the name of the country in which I live.

Comment: So it's saber not conocer?

Comment: _Saber mi país_ means to know the name of my country. _Conocer mi país_ means know the country itself (the cities, rivers...).

Comment: Good answer, I think you could really build ought on the facts bit.  Saber with nouns always refers to facts *about* something: saber *el nombre*, *la fecha de nacimiento*, *el peso* de alguien.  That is, each individual datum that may be returned by an interrogative as in ¿Sabes qué/dónde/cuál/cómo/cuánto/cuándo …? use saber.  Conocer rejects that type of construction

Answer (score 1):

I can see there's been a lot of excellent debate on this matter. I would add, just to help, that the verb saber comes usually with another verb o with a phrase. For example:

> Yo sé leer. - I know how to read.

In this first case, saber is related to an ability.

> Yo sé que hoy lloverá. - I know that it'll rain today.

In this other case, saber is related to facts that you know. But, in both cases, saber is related to a dominated subject.

Conocer is, on the other hand, a verb that should always be followed by an object (direct or indirect):

> Yo conozco París. - I know Paris.
>
> Yo te conozco. I know you.

And, as the rest of commenters have stated, conocer is sometimes a verb that denotes a general state of awareness or general knowledge. But, as we can see, when you KNOW (conocer) someone, or when you know Paris, it means that you genuinely know the person, or place, in a very profound way. This, evidently, will depend on the context. But I'd say that, in most cases, saber and conocer are only different in the way that they build their sentences - saber with phrases or verbs, conocer with objects.

Cheers.

Comment: Two things: It's a bit misleading to say that "on the other hand", conocer is should always be followed by an object — saber takes direct objects: ¿Sabes *que hoy va a llover*?  Sí, *lo* sé.  Also, *conocer* rarely takes indirect objects.  If you see *le* with it, it's almost always a case of *leísmo* (I can't think of any context in which "te lo conozco", would make sense, for instance, and *le conoce* can always be replaced with *lo conoce*